# Не работает :nth-child. Как исправить?

Tags: html, css

Я хочу третий элемент перекрасить в фиолетовый, выбираю его через `:nth-child`.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.col_item {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.item {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.col_item:ntn-child(3) > .item {
    background: purple;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="col_item">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col_item">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col_item">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Почему не получается выбрать элемент?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас опечатка в слове `nth-child` - вы написали `ntn-child`:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.col_item {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.item {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.col_item:nth-child(3) > .item {
    background: purple;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="col_item">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col_item">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col_item">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```